How to open file with a specific Application Bundle?
I wrote an application in Qt for macOS & Windows. Now we want to communicate with that app from the browser using custom protocols. As it seems not possible to add this to Qt I tried to build a Cocoa helper app that just receives the message created in the browser  from macOS using a custom protocol. That so far works and was simple.
But I can't manage to get it to open a document in my (separate Qt) application.
Trial 1:
void launchApplicationBundleWithArguments(NSString *bundleIdentifier, NSString *executablePath, NSArray<NSString *> *arguments) 
{
    NSWorkspace *workspace = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
    NSURL *url = [workspace URLForApplicationWithBundleIdentifier:bundleIdentifier];
    
    if (url) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        
        NSDictionary *configuration = @{NSWorkspaceLaunchConfigurationArguments: launchArguments};
      
        if (![workspace launchApplicationAtURL:url options:NSWorkspaceLaunchDefault configuration:configuration error:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Error launching application: %@", error);
        }   
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Application bundle with identifier %@ not found", bundleIdentifier);
    }
}

This launches my application, but won't send the file's path (stored in arguments) to the command line of my main application. No error is reported.
Trial 2:
NSWorkspaceOpenConfiguration* configuration = [NSWorkspaceOpenConfiguration new];
[configuration setArguments: launchArguments];
 [configuration setPromptsUserIfNeeded: YES];
 [workspace openApplicationAtURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath: executablePath] configuration: configuration completionHandler:^(NSRunningApplication* app, NSError* error) {
   if (error) {
     NSLog(@"Failed to run the app: %@", error.localizedDescription);
   }
 }];

This fails with a message box saying that my helper application does not have sufficient access rights to start the other application.
How can this be done?

Are your apps sandboxed?  Docs for the arguments property of NSWorkspaceOpenConfiguration  say "If the calling process is sandboxed, the system ignores the value of this property."

@JWWalker I cant tell. How do i find out?

Usually you would know whether it is sandboxed because you set that option when you built the app.  But it is also possible to show a column in the Activity Monitor utility to see which running apps are sandboxed.

Excuse the delay - i now checked in the Activity Monitor - and the application reports being NOT sand boxed. I can start the application from a terminal with parameters successfully. Any ideas?

There are two applications here, the one being launched and the one doing the launching.  Which one are you saying is not sandboxed?

The helper application was indeed sandboxed! Obviously that is the default setting! That was the problem. Work now as expected. @JWWalker Thank you so much.

@JWWalker: Please answer this question, so i can accept it.

According to the documentation of the arguments property of the NSWorkspaceOpenConfiguration class, a sandboxed app cannot pass arguments to another app that it is launching.  So make sure that your helper application is not sandboxed.
